# How do I use UIKit Dynamics to bring a view out elastically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, ios7

I want to bring a view onto the view controller in somewhat of an elastic/rubber-bandy motion. Basically, the UIView is off screen to the right, then slides and "rubber-bands" into place.

Is this something I should just be using UIView animations for? Or is this something I could use the new UIKit Dynamics for? The snap one seems reasonably close, but it always "tumbles" it.

Answer (score 0):

Snap is probably closest.

You may want to try adjusting the dampening. I found this post helpful:

http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/61654699557/ui-dynamics-in-ios-7-ios-7-is-gold-master-it